# useEffect fires twice even when strict mode is disabled and with an empty array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useFetch effect that pulls saome data from the db. The data is being pulled to the top App.js component.
My useEtch effect has an empty array and I cancled strict mode, but still the useFecth function fires twice on each load and the whole App component including it's sub components are being rendered twiice.

The useEffect itself is only fired once, see the comments in the code.

**How do I stop sub components like the`<Navbar />`from rendering twice and why does the useFetch is being called twice?**

```
//App.js
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(false)
  useFetch('/api/path', setData) 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Navbar />
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      </header>
      <div>
        {data ? <Data data={data} /> : 'LOADING...'}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Data({data}) {
  return(
    <ul>
      //Display data code
    </ul>
  )
}

//useFetch.js
export default function useFetch(path, options) {                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  console.log('useFetch fires') //Fires twice on each load                                                                                                               
  useEffect(() => {
  console.log('useEffct fires') //Fires once on each load                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    const fetchData = async () => {                                                                                                               
      try {                                                                                                                                       
        const response = await fetch(path)                                                                                                                                                       
        const newData = await response.json()                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        return setData(newData)                                                                                                                   
      }                                                                                                                                           
      catch (err) {                                                                                                                               
        if (err) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
          return setData({error:'something went wrong!'})                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                                                         
      }                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                             
    fetchData()                                                                                                                                   
  }, [])                                                                                                                                      
  return data                                                                                                                                     
}
```

Comment: You are calling `setData` which rerenders `App` which calls `useFetch`. This is the correct behavior

Comment: So I'm doing everything correctly? How can I stop components like <Navbar/> from rendering twice then?

Comment: You can use [memo](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo) but usually you should just let components rerender

Comment: Let it re-render, it's fine. If it's expensive or you don't like extra db calls, consider using something like react query that caches instead of just a raw fetch.